# How to display "fields"' value from the database in a Pug file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query, pug

I use `MongoDBClient` in `Node.js`, and `Pug`.

I would want to get all my pizzerias' name in my database. Thus, I wrote this line : `collection.find({cook:'Pizza'})` to select all the pizzerias, and the attribute "name" exists.

But `find` returns a cursor, thus I can't directly use its return like that : `var array_pizzerias_names = collection.find({cook:'Pizza'}).get('name')`. (NB : I know the funciton `get` doesn't exist).

How could I do it ?

In my Pug file, I wrote these few lines :

```
        - for(var i = 0; i < array_pizzerias_names.length; i++) {
            p=array_pizzerias_names[i].name
        - }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

`MongoClient` (`require('mongodb').MongoClient`) provides a `find` method signature which takes 2 parameters, and the second is a callback ; the last parameter of the latter is a `cursor` which have a method `toArray`.

The method `toArray` takes a callback ; its last parameter is the `array` containing all the results of the `find`, and can be used in Pug.

The below code works.

**Node.js code (JavaScript file) :**

```
        collection.find({cuisine: speciality}, (error, cursor) => {
            handleError(error, res);

            cursor.toArray((error, array_results) => {
                handleError(error, res);

                app.locals.speciality = speciality;
                app.locals.array_documents = array_results;
                res.render("speciality.pug");

            });
        });
```

**Pug file :**

```
doctype html
html(lang='fr')
    head
        title='Speciality'
        body
            h1 Speciality : #{speciality} - Number of buildings : #{array_documents.length}
            - for(var i = 0; i < array_documents.length; i++) {
                p=array_documents[i].name + " - Address : " + array_documents[i].address.street + " " + array_documents[i].borough + ", building n°" + array_documents[i].address.building
            - }
```